# Xamarin Forms - Control Fusion

Tags: xamarin

Is it possible, in xamarin, to create a fusion of multiple control?

By Example, I want an `ImageButton` (I have other idea of fusion, just an example), I can place an `Image` and then, put a transparent `Button` onto this one.

**But is it possible to create an object which is a fusion of the both?** Without renderer or with?

Thank in advance !

## Edit 1

```
public class ImageButton : Image, Button
{

}
```

I mean a fusion like that where I just add some properties. Then by a renderer  or something like that, I can interact over each platform to use my properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you could create a Custom View in code or `XAML`. That `View` will have the `Image` and the `Button`. Then you can use the that custom view whenever you want.

Example in code:

```cs
public class TagView : ContentView
{       
    public TagView()
    {
        Content = new StackLayout()
        {
            Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical,
            Children = 
            {
                new Image(),
                new Button()
            }
        };
    }             
}
```

Use it like this:

```xml
<ContentPage ...
  xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:YOURNAMESPACE.Controls;assembly=YOURNAMESPACE"
  ...>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <controls:TagView 
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Wow, interesting ! So if I want a ImageButton, then I can do the following code : `Content = new StackLayout() { new Image(), new Button()};`? Thank for your answer !

Comment: I think, you answer doesn't really answer my question, but maybe I missunderstand your answer, I wrote an edit :)

Comment: You could achieve some kind of fusion using the solution i gave, but you must add properties to the class to interact with the button and image.